# How to Get Values Of [@attributes] Element Using SimpleXML In PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have problem accessing this attribue , $xml is my xml output using simpleXML .... here is the part of xml :

```
[component] => Array
 (
      [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
          (
              [observationMedia] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                  (
                      [@attributes] => Array
                          (
                              [ID] => L30b39868-2c02-4f22-817f-3fc8ff059193
                          )
                     [text] => image description
                      [value] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                          (
                              [@attributes] => Array
                                  (
                                      [mediaType] => image/jpeg
                                  )
                             [reference] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                  (
                                      [@attributes] => Array
                                          (
                                              [value] => Label2.jpg
                                          )
                                  )
                          )
                  )
          )          
  )
```

)

I am able to access the [text] element using this :

```
$xml->component->observationMedia->text
```

But Unable to access the attribute value , I tried this but didnot work :

```
$xml->component->observationMedia->value->reference->attributes()->value
```

If I use @attributes , then its gives error in php ...

Here is the xml data :

```
<component>
<observationMedia ID="L30b39868-2c02-4f22-817f-3fc8ff059193">
    <text>image description</text>
    <value mediaType="image/jpeg" xsi:type="ED">
        <reference value="Label2.jpg" />
    </value>
</observationMedia>
</component>
```

Comment: How did you check that it did not work?

Comment: by echoing the value in php ... I was able to access the [text] , but not the [@attribute] value

Comment: So what is the exact output of your attempt? With `...value->reference->attributes()->value`

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object in ....

Comment: I am trying to echo Label2.jpg as output ...

Comment: In where? Do a debug. What is considered `non-object`

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the xml data , I have solved my problem ..
Here is how I have got the attribute value :

```
echo (string) $component ->observationMedia ->value->reference['value']
```

Looking at the xml value has helped me ....